# Send bytes stream by socket c++ failure

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, stream-socket-client

I'm tying to send with a socket a byte stream but my problem is that the client app cant receive all the stream.
I made a loop to send all the stream I call the function 'recv' but there comes a time when this function does not read all the buffer in the parameter and the application crash

qDebug only print in the console of qt

How can I send all the bytes stream without know how many bytes the client will receive?

```
char rec[256];
int bytesRcvd = recv(s,rec,255,0); 
while(bytesRcvd)
{ 
  if(bytesRcvd==-1)
    { 
      qDebug()<<"Error";
      break;
    }
 rec[bytesRcvd]= '\0'; 
 qDebug()<<rec;
 bytesRcvd = recv(s,rec,255,0);
}
```

Comment: You'll need to send the size of the data beforehand (in network byte order), thus the receiving part will know how many data will be send.

Comment: Why are you not using Qt for all this?! In any case, the bare minimum is to provide the crash backtrace.

Comment: `this function does not read all the buffer`. What does it read? How do you know it's not all the buffer? Can you show a session transcript? *And why an application should crash because of a network error?*